# fontFamily and fontWeight not working in TextAppearance

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I am trying to add multiple font-families in my app. Following is code that adds "inter" font.

Here's `values/typography.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeBold" format="reference" />
    <attr name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeSemiBold" format="reference" />
    <attr name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeMediumBold" format="reference" />

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.DisplayLarge">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_font_family</item>
        <item name="fontWeight">400</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Bold">
        <item name="fontWeight">700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.SemiBold">
        <item name="fontWeight">600</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Medium">
        <item name="fontWeight">500</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here's `font/inter_font_family.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:font="@font/inter_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        app:font="@font/inter_medium"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500" />
    <font
        app:font="@font/inter_semibold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="600" />
    <font
        app:font="@font/inter_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

Here's `themes.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLarge">@style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeBold">
        @style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Bold
    </item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeSemiBold">
        @style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.SemiBold
    </item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeMediumBold">
        @style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Medium
    </item>
</style>
```

My primary problem is that `fontWeight` has no effect in `TextAppearance` styles. If I set individual fonts (inter_bold, inter_light, etc) in `TextAppearance` styles, it works and shows correct fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `fontWeight` attribute might not be applied correctly when specifying a font family in the `TextAppearance` style.

By the way, you can define separate styles for each font weight in your typography.xml file. See bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.DisplayLarge">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_regular</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Bold">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.SemiBold">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_semibold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Medium">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_medium</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In this example, each `TextAppearance` style explicitly specifies the desired font file. This way, the `fontWeight` attribute should have the expected effect since it's now applied to a specific font file.

Ensure to update the themes.xml file to incorporate these styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLarge">@style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeBold">@style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Bold</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeSemiBold">@style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.SemiBold</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceDisplayLargeMediumBold">@style/TextAppearance.App.DisplayLarge.Medium</item>
</style>
```

This should resolve the issue with the `fontWeight` attribute not taking effect. Each `TextAppearance` style now explicitly specifies the font file, allowing you to control both the font family and weight.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand, and I already mentioned this way in the question itself, thank you.